# Sql não reconhece a pelica

Tags: php, sql

Eu estou com um problema em que o sql não reconhece a pelica

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-left">
                    <select name="utilizadores" >
                        <option value="0">Utilziadores ativados</option>
                        <option value="1">utilizadores arquivados</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="form-inputs name">
                    <p>Pesquisar por nome</p>

                    <input type="text" name="pesnomeuser" placeholder=""  />


                </div>



 if(isset($_POST['procura'])){
            $procura=$_POST['pesnomeuser'];
            $utilizadores=$_POST['utilizadores'];

            $sql=sprintf("select * from users  where  NOMEUSER   like '%s' or USER like '%s' and arquivo='%t' order by NOMEUSER asc;","%".$procura."%","%".$procura."%",$utilizadores);
            $a=mysqli_query($ligacao,$sql);
            ?>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Nome de utilizador</th> 
            </tr>
            <?php while ($reg_sql=mysqli_fetch_array($a)){  ?>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $reg_sql['NOMEUSER']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $reg_sql['USER']; ?></td>
            <td>

            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <a href="utilizadores.php?edit=<?php echo $reg_sql['ID_USER']; ?>" class="edit_btn" >Editar</a>

        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <a href="utilizadores.php?eliminar=<?php echo $reg_sql['ID_USER']; ?>" class="edit_btn" >Eliminar</a>
        </td>
            </tr>

            <?php }
            ?>
            </table>
        <?php   
        }
```

Comment: Qual erro é apresentado?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\empresa\utilizadores.php on line 221

Comment: O nome do seu campo é `USER` mesmo? então deve colocar ele entre crases

Comment: Sim é, já experimentei mil e uma maneiras e não consigo

Comment: Se me puder ajudar agradecia muito

Comment: Deixa assim `\`USER\` like '%s'`

Comment: continua na mesma

Comment: Deixe sua consutla assim: `$a=mysqli_query($ligacao,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($ligacao));` veja se aparece algum outro erro.

Comment: agora dá-me este erro Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a '%' or USER like '%'%' and arquivo='' order by NOMEUSER asc' na linha 1